# Adding infinite number of obstacles in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to make a flappy bird game in pygame for school but i am struggling with adding the obstacles. I can add one obstacle but i want to add infinite obstacles and i already have an infinite loop to run my game so when i add an extra infinite, loop my game just crashes. I am using a `time.sleep()` function when add the obstacle in my infinite loop which makes the game crash.
This is my code so far:

```py
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()

xSpeler = 450
ySpeler = 100
widthSpeler = 40
heightSpeler = 40
vel = 10
vel1 = 10

#obstacle 1
xo1 = 900
yo1 = 0
ho1 = 200
wo1 = 50 
xo2 = 900
yo2 = 350
ho2 = 200
wo2 = 50
#obstacle 2
xo3 = 900
yo3 = 0
ho3 = 250
wo3 = 50
xo4 = 900
yo4 = 350
ho4 = 150
wo4 = 50
  
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
bi = pygame.image.load('bada.png')
      
pygame.display.flip()

run = True
while run:  
    win.blit(bi, (0, 0))
    pygame.time.delay(1)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    ySpeler += vel
    if ySpeler >= 500 - heightSpeler:
        ySpeler = 500 - heightSpeler
    
    xo1 -= vel1
    xo2 -= vel1

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and xSpeler> vel and ySpeler > 0:
        ySpeler -= jump

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (xSpeler, ySpeler, widthSpeler, heightSpeler))
    for x in range(100):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0),(xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0),(xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2))
        time.sleep(7)
    
    pygame.display.update()

im came from netherland so my inglish is not so good and my variables are in dutch so sorry for it
i realy hope someone can help me.
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback you get.

Comment: i dont get a traceback but i just dont know how i can add infinity obstacles
sorry that it was unclear and thanks for react.

Comment: then how does the game 'just crash'?  when does it crash?

Comment: if i add an extra infinity loop or add a for x in range what you see in the code than the screen just stay black.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen stays black because of `time.sleep(7)`. It is in a for loop that iterate 100 times so that's your program sleeping 700 seconds every frame. To make an obstacle, make a function that generates and returns 2 obstacles, one for top and the other one for bottom.

```
def genObstacle():
    # generate and return
    #1. pygame surface for top and bottom rects
    #2. initial position for top rect and bottom rect
    topHeight = random.randint(10, 200) # height for bottom obstacle
    botHeight = random.randint(10, 200) # height for top obstacle
    top = pygame.Surface((10, topHeight)).convert()
    bot = pygame.Surface((10, botHeight)).convert()
    # return: top rect, bottom rect, top rect's position, bottom rect's position

    return [top, bot, [800, 0], [800, 500-botHeight]]
```

Return the initial positions for both of the obstacles as well, so it is easier to work with. I would really recommend using a class for obstacle, so working with attributes of obstacles like position is easier.

Now that we have a function to generate obstacle, we can make a list to hold those obstacles `obstacles = []`. Now, we can generate the obstacles every 3 seconds like this:

```
#other code
start = time.time()
while True:
    #other code
    now = time.time()
    if now - start > 3:
        obstacles.append(genObstacle())
        start = now
```

Now that we have obstacles, we can change draw them and change their values like this:

```
for i in range(len(obstacles)):
    # remember, third item in list is position for top and
    # fourth item is the position for bottom
    
    # draw the obstacles
    win.blit(obstacles[i][0], (obstacles[i][2][0], obstacles[i][3][1]))
    win.blit(obstacles[i][1], (obstacles[i][2][0], obstacles[i][3][1]))

    # change the x values for it to move to the right
    obstacles[i][2][0] -= 1
    obstacles[i][2][0] -= 1
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer my question i am not verry good in programming but i think i can use this so thank you so much.

Comment: i have try this code for a while  now and i have a little bit struglen with the append() function do i have to import something or can i not use this code in pycharm(the ide i use)

Comment: append is a python function to add items to a list so you dont have to import anything

Comment: but if i add append in pycharm he says that  obstacles(the def function i create)has no atribute append.

Comment: That is because you are not meant to add items to a function. `.append` is an attribute of a list not a function. You should do `listname.append(obstacle)`

Comment: sorry i think my reactions are really 
exhausting i dont know what in my code the listname is so
her is the code with append:
                                     obstacles.append(genObstacle())

Comment: It will be really difficult to do what you are doing without using OOP, one being scope problems like you are having right now. If `obstacles` is your list name and and you are getting the error "function has no attribute append", then you must be using the same name for list and function. It is really hard for me to tell without seeing your code, so i strongly suggest you ask a new question. Better chances of your problem being solved that way.

Comment: thank you verry much i really think that without your answers it was never succeed i think that with all your answers thit wil became th best game i have ever programd so thank you.